# XP Pro somehow became XP home

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, windows-edition

**I installed XP Pro SP2** on a newly formatted C: drive on the same Dell Dimension 8100 computer that had been previously running XP Pro.  It worked fine.

I went to
Update.Microsoft.com
and installed all the high priority fixes, including SP3, and most of the other updates.

Now, the **computer reports that it is running XP home!**

What happened?  More importantly, **how do I get back to XP Pro?**

---

added comments:

1. My installation disk is an original Dell OEM disk labeled "Microsoft Windows XP Professional".
2. prodspec.ini contains:

[SMS Inventory Identification]
Version=1.0

[Product Specification]
Product=Windows XP Home Edition

Version=5.0
Localization=English
ServicePackNumber=0
BitVersion=40 
[Version]
DriverVer=07/01/2001,5.1.2600.0

---

3. I looked for gpedit.msc and it does not exist.
   I also checked a backup I did after first installing XP pro and it did not exist there either.
4. Finally, I checked prodspec.ini from the same backup.  It also says XP home.
5. So is it really possible that the original Dell OEM installation disk has the wrong version on it?  (Can I look at any file on the CD itself to tell for sure?

---

Comment: Have you checked your license key?

Comment: Open this ini file with notepad, see that it says and post it by editing your original post, do not change anything in there....`%systemroot%\system32\prodspec.ini`

Comment: It was M$'s way of telling you to move on to Windows 7 already...

Comment: is it merely reporting XP home, or is it ACTUALLY xp home? Just curious. Can you do start --> run --> gpedit.msc ?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this same issue.  I recently reinstalled Windows XP Professional on a 5-year old Dell desktop using the disk from Dell, and thought I was going insane when I realized that XP Home was actually installed.  After wasting a bunch more time on this, I finally figured out that Dell had shipped a mislabeled disk.  If you've got another XP Pro disk, try it.  Otherwise, I guess you could try contacting Dell.

Comment: -1 your answer is written in a stupid way. Your second sentence said you installed xp pro, then says it was xp home. You should have just said it right the first time. Why should people reading have to relive all your muddled thinking, since you got it unmuddled you may as well have written it in a logical clear way that is more use.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote since it seems a fairly relevant problem.  And maybe you got the problem spot on.  You should've just said Dell shipped you an XP Home CD labelled as XP Pro, and that may have happened to him.

Answer (score 0):

Open Notepad, create a file with "reg" extension and paste in the following text (pay attention on number **N** in CurrentControlSet00(**N**), where **N** max number of your "CurrentControlSet00") if, **N** equal for example 3, than:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet003\Control\Pr­oductOptions]
"ProductType"="WinNT"
"ProductSuite"=hex(7):50,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,6f,00,6e,00,61,00,6c,00,00,00,00,\00
```

Run it, restart system and press <kbd>F8</kbd> and choice "Last Known Good..."

Comment: That really could do with some explanation(what it does, what options are, why you think it will work), not just instruction.

Comment: [HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\Pr­oductOptions] - this section of registry defines version of WinXP. "ProductSuite" - professional, "Brand" - Home edition.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you discovered this?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that this will perhaps make things like the splash screen display XP Pro, while the internals are still XP Home.  It certainly can't add the missing executables.

Comment: Reinstall ServicePack